# Operations research : minimize the absolute value instead of square

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, operations-research

I am working on an operations research problem
In a previous work, they minimized the square of a-b : 
min sum (a-b)²
I would like to work on a linear problem, by minimizing the absolute value of (a-b)
I do not how how to provide a mathematical proof
Knowing that it does not change the purpose of the problem, and in the previous work, the use of square was not justified.
Thank for the support

Comment: There is a difference between minimizing the sum of squares and minimizing the sum of absolute values. In the first case the deviations are squared while in the second case the deviations are not squared.

Comment: You are correct, finding $\min \sum |a_i-b_i|$ is a linear problem, unlike $\min \sum (a_i-b_i)^2$. But they will not usually result in the same $\arg \min$...

Comment: This is the point, I would like to work on linear problem, because the square deviation will not affect the analysis. But I do not know how to proof it mathematically.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want a proof?

Comment: Can you please give a clearer idea of the kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: See [this post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/114/how-to-minimize-an-absolute-value-in-the-objective-of-an-lp) on or.stackexchange for two linearizations of absolute value minimization.

Comment: In a LP, you go about this by having two constraints. One is $d>a-b$. The other is $d>b-a$. Then you minimise $d$.